# if input string is same as the reversed output string, it should display reversed word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, for-loop

I am trying to check if the input string is the same as the reversed output string, and if so, it should display reversed word.

```
var word = "cel";
var reverseWord = "lec";

for (i=0; i < word.length; i++) {       
    for (j=0; j < reverseWord.length; j++) {
        if (word[i] === reverseWord[j] && word[i+1] === reverseWord[j+1] && word[i+2] === reverseWord[j+2]) {
            console.log("reverseWord----->");
        } 
    }  
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a function which checks if given word is a palindrome?

Comment: if the word is the same backwards they should be equal so just check if they are equal from the beginning, right? maybe i misunderstand

Comment: @JoeLloyd joe should match eoj ....can you update in my code its confusing :(

Comment: @Kinduser not the palindrome just reverse should match

Comment: Then reverse the word `word.split('').reverse().join('')` and compare with the original word.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if a reversed string is the same as another string, simply use below code

```js
var word = "cel";
var reverseWord = "lec";
console.log(word.split("").reverse().join("") === reverseWord);
```

Comment: is there a way to write a code without use reverse method ??

Comment: Sure, but why would you want to do that? @texirv

Comment: thats the requirement

Comment: hello can you help me with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600110/minimise-the-code-since-i-am-using-the-same-code-only-the-content-in-p-tags-chan

Answer (score 1):

Without using the reverse method

```js
var word = "cel";
var reverseWord = "lec";
var arr = [];
  for(i=word.length-1;i>=0;i--){
  arr.push(word[i]);
  }
var new_word = arr.join("");
  if(new_word === reverseWord){
  console.log("true");
  }
  else{
  console.log("false");
  }
```

So  you can use an array to **push** individual characters of the string into it in reverse order using a loop and convert the array back into a string using **join()** method and do the check. Hope this helps.